# Making solr 7.2 use coord in ranking

Tags: solr, lucene

If I have a search term like, "foo bar" I would like documents with both foo and bar to receive a bonus as compared to documents that only contain "foo" or "bar".

In solr 5.5 I was able to do this by having a custom similarity that extended "org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity" and overwriting the coord function.  When I had done this, documents with only a partial match (e.g. something with just "foo") got hit by a penalty as compared to documents that had both a "foo" and a "bar".

In solr 7.2, near as I can tell the BM25 class does not use the coord function at all.  How can I make it so documents with fewer of the search terms are given a penalty?

Comment: Exactly what use case caused you to have to make a custom similarity class for this? This is the _default_ behaviour for both the old, classic similarity and BM25 - documents that have both terms are ranked above those just have one of them. That being said, you can still use your own similarity class - ClassicSimilarity is still available.

Comment: I don't see the penalty being applied to documents that only have one of the two search terms when I run a debug query.  In solr 5.5 there is a coord factor that goes into the overall score, but in solr 7.2 that coord is missing.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't need a custom similarity class to make a document with both terms score higher than a document with just one of the terms - this is the default behaviour in Lucene.

Comment: Lucene scores them by adding the "points" earned by each term independently.  A document that is a phenomenal match for "foo" can score better than a document with mediocre matches for both "foo" and "bar".  The old version of solr took the "points" earned by summing each term's match and then multiplying the result by the coord factor.  While it was still theoretically possible for a partial match to outscore a full match, this was less likely because of the coord factor.

Comment: Wouldn't that be fixed by disabling termfreqs and norms? I'm not sure what other differences you'd see when the score is being calculated for each term?

Comment: I don't want those to be disabled, I just want to make it so documents that don't match all terms are given a pretty heavy penalty as compared to documents that match all terms.  For example, I don't consider all documents that have the same number of matches to be identical in quality, which is what I think could happen if termfreqs and norms were disabled.

Comment: @zelinka, I'm curious as if you ever figured out a way? As far as I know, Lucene 7 removed coords calculation accross the code base, as well as removed the "freq" properties in all scorers (which were used to calculate the coord). I know that BM25 let you set the k1 parameter to adjust the term frequency saturation curve, so that matching a lot of terms yield to higher scores than matching a single term multiple time, but that still not enough to replication what coords were achieving in classic similarity.

Comment: I wrote a custom similarity that would add 1000 for every match, which would make it so the thousands place would control how many terms matched, and the rest of the score which is on the order of 20 or so for a really good match would be used as a tie breaking criteria.  If the query consists of 10 terms and one document matches 9 of them and another matches 8 terms this would cause the 9 match document to be ahead and the BM25 score would be used as a tie break for documents with the same number of matched terms.